# How to retrieve user names of commenters on an Instagram post

Tags: c#, .net, instagram, instagram-api

I have set a session cookie and can make a request to:
`https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1` to get a list of the media ids (shortcodes).

I can then navigate to `https://www.instagram.com/p/{shortcode}/` to view the media. However, I can't view the page source as it is populated by some JavaScript execution.

Is there a way to either view the page source after JavaScript execution, or another way to obtain the usernames of people who have commented?

Thank you

Comment: I am sure twitter would want you to use their api, I am also sure they wouldn't want you scraping their site. However, if you want the results from a page after render and all the funky javascript, you will have to render it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool Swagger-Codegen to generate APIs for a bunch of websites.
Haven't tried with IG but a quick search on google gave me this:
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/saketthakare/instagram/1.0.0

You can use Export -> Client SDK -> your programming language to generate a client API.

EDIT: This might also interest you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api